# How to put together the results of functions of several tables in one query?

Tags: sql-server, function, group-by

I have two tables, for example ONE and TWO, my tables are bigger and with different structures, but have some fields that coincide.

[image]

How can I get the table QUERY?

I can do it with just one table WITH GROUP and SUM, but how can I add the last column in QUERY? Is it possible?

```
SELECT Date, SUM(Apples), SUM(Oranges) FROM One
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your English. Esquece essa bobagem  de "sorry for my English" ;)

Comment: Thanks, I always say that to avoid confusions :P

Comment: Ok, but please avoid doing it here :P . . . It is [considered noise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202977/should-im-not-a-native-english-speaker-lines-be-removed), just like ["hello, thanks, regards"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Date, one.place, SUM(Apples), SUM(Oranges), SUM(Grapes) 
FROM One left join Two on one.place = two.place and one.[Date] = two.[Date]
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: Thanks to all, that's what I needed. I still have work to do with my query, but I have the path to follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT one.Date, one.place, SUM(Apples), SUM(Oranges), SUM(Grapes) 
FROM One left join Two on one.place = two.place and one.date = two.date
GROUP BY one.date, one.place
```

Will return all places in first table and the correct counts